# Sizzling Sound on Yosemite in Multi-Output (Aggregate Device) from the 2. Device

Tags: macos, audio, midi

I recently wanted to play my music through multiple output devices at once:

- My Macbook Pro's internal speakers
- Bluetooth Speakers

As i have found [from the internet](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH5178?locale=en_US) i have created a Multi-Output Device through Utilities/Audio MIDI Setup, and it works. The problem is, **the 2nd device (not the one which is selected as master device) gives a sizzling sound**, which is independent of the source. So, when I select the Built-in Output as master, the bluetooth speaker sizzles, and when I select the bluetooth speaker, my built-in speaker.

Does anyone have this problem?

Comment: Not something I've heard of [or tried] before, but I'd guess something is having difficulty keeping up with the synced protocols… bluetooth is going to put a strain on any kind of audio synchronisation, as it's a 'drifting' protocol, with no audio time-stamp. Have you tested the master clock options in Audio/Midi?

Comment: I have play around with the Drift Correction settings, and the sound format settings (just editable for the built-in), i think i tried all the settings  combinations i see there.. I did not any selectable Clock options as i remember. When i am at home, i can look at again, but what should i expect to see exactly?

Comment: I think I might be having the same problem, did you ever find an explanation or solution to this?

Comment: No.. İ have simply given up.

Answer (score 1):

Try making sure that your source format (Hz) and bitrate are set to the same on both devices.  My guess is that if they are different, you may have one receiving information at one rate but transmitting as another.